# Ruby recursive method needs return clause

Tags: ruby

I could be missing the obvious here, but this code is failing unless I use the `return` clause when call it recursively on `Net::HTTPRedirection` case.

```
  def fetch_headers(limit = REDIRECT_LIMIT)
    # You should choose a better exception.
    raise ArgumentError, 'too many HTTP redirects' if limit == 0
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true if @uri.scheme == 'https'
    request_uri = @uri.request_uri.nil? ? '/' : @uri.request_uri
    http.request_head(request_uri) do |response|
      case response
      when Net::HTTPSuccess then
        return response
      when Net::HTTPRedirection then
        location = response['location']
        parsed_location = URI.parse location
        @uri = parsed_location.absolute? ? parsed_location : @uri.merge(parsed_location)
        fetch_headers(limit - 1)
      else
        return response.value
      end
    end
  end
```

The caller method:

```
  def perform(link_id)
    link = Link.find(link_id)
    url = link.url =~ /^http/ ? link.url : "http://#{link.url}"
    @uri = URI.parse url
    headers = fetch_headers
    case headers.content_type
    when /application/
      filename = File.basename(@uri.path)
      link.update title: filename
    when /html/
      response = fetch_page
      page = Nokogiri::HTML(response)
      link.update title: page_title(page), description: page_description(page)
    else
      logger.warn "URL #{url} with unknow mime-type: #{headers.content_type}"
    end
  end
```

Here is the spec I am running:

```
it 'follows the redirects using relative URL' do
  link = create(:link, url: url)
  path = '/welcome.html'
  stub_request(:head, url).to_return(status: 302, body: '',
                                     headers: { 'Location' => path })
  redirect_url = "#{url}#{path}"
  stub_request(:head, redirect_url).to_return(status: 200, body: '',
                                              headers: html_header)
  stub_request(:get, redirect_url).to_return(status: 200, body: title_html_raw,
                                             headers: html_header)

  UrlScrapperJob.perform_now link.id
  link.reload
  expect(link.title).to match(/page title/)
end
```

Here are the result of `fetch_headers` method:

**With the return clause**: `#<Net::HTTPOK 200  readbody=true>`

**Without the return clause**: `#<Net::HTTPFound 302  readbody=true>`

The result I would expect would be the `HTTPOK 200` because it should follow the redirects until a 200 OK.

Comment: Can you add some detail to what you mean by "failing"?

Comment: @Linuxios I have updated the result and explained the mean of failing.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the value, returned from `fetch_headers` function.

`return` returns it’s argument as a result of a function call.

Without explicit `return`, the return value is what `http.request_head(request_uri, &block)` returns, which is apparently causes the infinite recursion.

You might want to try

```
http.request_head(request_uri) do |response|
  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then
    response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then
    location = response['location']
    parsed_location = URI.parse location
    @uri = parsed_location.absolute? ? parsed_location : @uri.merge(parsed_location)
    fetch_headers(limit - 1)
  else
    response.value
  end
end.tap { |result| puts result } # ⇐ here
```

to examine what is actual result without explicit `return`.

Comment: Please check my update, to see the result in both cases.

Comment: The thing you are missing here is probably that `return` **returns from all the codeblocks to the topmost level**. The control flow in case of 302 is: `fetch`⇒`fetch`⇒[inside 2 blocks]⇒`200`⇒[inside 1]⇒`302` due to recursion. Normal control flow forces the first yielded result (302) to be returned as a function result. OTOH, `return` returns it’s result to the top level.